# Azure Web Sites: Free, Shared, Reserved difference?

Tags: azure

I have ASP.NET website + database. I want to try to deploy it into ms cloud. 
I look to Azure "[Web Sites](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/)".
I don't understand clearly what difference between Free, Shared, Reserved.
What I need to use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out this link: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/#header-1 and click on Web Sites link on the left hand side. This should give you an idea about the differences between 3 models.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Check out this link below, it clearly explains you the differences between free, shared and reserved website modes.

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/web-sites/how-to-scale-websites/#freemode

Hope this helps.!